# How to copy all the text (using ctrl + c and ctrl + a comands) from a text file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, file, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a Selenium Project.

I tried to make a function that copies all the text inside a text file using ctrl + A, ctrl + C.

```
def Copy(driver) :
    f = open("out1.txt") # open the text file

        .click() #i need to click on the file
        .send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a') # select all the text
    time.sleep(1)
        .send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c') # copy the text in my clipboard

    f.close()
```

That s what I tried to code, but I did not manage.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Python's built in file read/write functions.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

For your example, you could do this.

```
with open('out1.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

Comment: I know that, but I specifically need the CTRL + A and CTRL + C command for my problem...

Comment: I see, is it a file on the web? Typically this works for files on disk.

Comment: It s a file on my pc. I ll try if you say that it might work.